# Remove the gridlines from first cell in a grid view

Tags: css, vb.net, gridview, datagridview

I am using VS 2015 and VB.NET

I have a grid view.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridCommodityPrices" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="commodityGridView" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridCommodityHeader">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCommoditDesc" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Day">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCommodityDay" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DayPrice") %>' CssClass="txtDataEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Peak">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCommodityPeak" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Peak") %>' CssClass="txtDataEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Next Week">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCommodityNextWeek" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NextWeek") %>' CssClass="txtDataEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Which looks like this

[image: Grid view before]

I want to be able to remove the grid lines from the upper left hand cell.  Specifically the left and top grid lines.  I have highlighted these in red below.

[image: Grid View after]

I have been playing about with the CSS using the `border-style` property but i'm getting no where.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you include the produced HTML?

Comment: @Gerard not sure what you mean, sorry